# Two-way ANOVA - getting the means

Tags: r

In r, how do I get the means of the different groups resulted by two-way ANOVA (the means of each of the combinations)?

Comment: Although somewhat on-topic here since it is programming related, you might get more/better answers on http://stats.stackexchange.com Or your question may already be asked and answered there.

Comment: Perhaps `aggregate` with your model formula and function `mean`?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
m1 <- lm(y~f1*f2,data=d)
predict(m1,newdata=with(d,expand.grid(f1=levels(f1),f2=levels(f2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a command for this.  Let's say your model is `m`.

```
model.tables(m, type = 'means')
```

Comment: Yes, though for the marginal means, be careful if you have an unbalanced design; see this question for details: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45878/3601